# How is this CSS scale effect achieved?

Tags: html, css, transform, webkit-transform

At http://www.thoughtspot.com/#forrester there is an image of three pieces of paper with "forrester" written on them. When you mouse over them they zoom in slightly, then when you move the mouse off, they scale back down. I'm using chrome and I see the following property applied:

-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);

But that seems to indicate no scaling/the original size only. I'm at a loss as to how the scaling is happening. Can anyone explain this one to me?

Comment: Note the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) state for `div#forrester`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showdev is correct, the :hover state has the following transition:

> body.front div#forrester:hover{
>
> -webkit-transform:scale(1.02,1.02);
>
> }

That seems obvious in hindsight.. may need caffeine.